# PyGtk How to change TreeView data using filter?

Tags: python, filtering, pygtk, gtktreeview

What I'm trying to do is dynamically change (via filter) list of strings. In my case it is list of files with paths stored in `gtk.TreeStore`.

Example of expected effect (eg. Sublime Text 2 file searching <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>):

Data:

List of files (treeview):

- '/home/user/'

  - '.bashrc',
  - 'test.txt',
- ...

Action: In filter field (Entry widget) user starts typing. After first character eg. 't' list should be updated like this:

Result:

List of files (treeview):

- 'test.txt',
- ... all strings containing 't' (matching function is not important now)

What I already have:

```
self.search_entry = gtk.Entry()

self.tree_store = gtk.TreeStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING, gobject.TYPE_BOOLEAN)

for node, files in self.files_list:
    parent = self.tree_store.append(None, [node, True])
    for f in files:
        self.tree_store.append(parent, [f, True])

tree_filter = self.tree_store.filter_new()
self.treeview = gtk.TreeView(tree_filter)

self.renderer0 = gtk.CellRendererText()
self.treeview.insert_column_with_attributes(-1, "Filename", self.renderer0, text=0)
self.treeview.set_search_column(0)
self.treeview.set_search_entry(self.search_entry)
self.treeview.expand_all()
```

I know that TreeView has a method `set_search_equal_func` where I can change default matching function to my own. The problem is how can I change the list during typing in filter form field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must read about [gtk.TreeModelFilter](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreemodelfilter.html). Here you can read a very useful example. It's C#, but it's very easy to "translate" it to python:

http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp_TreeView_Tutorial#Filtering_Data

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for that C# example link it was very useful. The key is to use `gtk.TreeModelFilter` methods `set_visible_func` and `refilter`.

Code looks like that now:

Somewhere in main app class:

```
def match_func(self, model, iterr, data=None):
    query = self.search_entry.get_buffer().get_text()
    value = model.get_value(iterr, 0)

    if query == "":
        return True
    elif query in value.lower():
        return True
    return False

def on_entry_refilter(self, widget, data=None):
    self.tree_filter.refilter()
```

Modified code:

```
self.search_entry = gtk.Entry()
self.search_entry.connect('changed', self.on_entry_refilter)

self.tree_store = gtk.TreeStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING, gobject.TYPE_BOOLEAN)

for node, files in self.files_list:
    parent = self.tree_store.append(None, [node, True])
    for f in files:
        self.tree_store.append(parent, [f, True])

self.tree_filter = self.tree_store.filter_new()
self.tree_filter.set_visible_func(self.match_func)
self.treeview = gtk.TreeView(self.tree_filter)

self.renderer0 = gtk.CellRendererText()
self.treeview.insert_column_with_attributes(-1, "Filename", self.renderer0, text=0)
self.treeview.set_search_column(0)
self.treeview.set_search_entry(self.search_entry)
self.treeview.expand_all()
```